# Hippo cms cache

Tags: caching, hippocms, page-caching

I switched on page caching in hippo cms as it written in this link https://www.onehippo.org/10/library/concepts/request-handling/hst-page-caching.html

After switching on cache, pages are loaded faster.
But problem is, this cache invalidated after a while.

Could anybody tell me, is there any settings in hippo where cache time is defined? or maybe it is not cache time problem?

I am using Hippo CMS 10.1.0 Community Edition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties file SpringComponentManager.properties inside hst-core library is where the ttl gets defined

```
pageCache.timeToLiveSeconds = 3600
```

Please refer to [1] for more details on how to override it.

[1] https://www.onehippo.org/10/library/concepts/web-application/hippo-cms-and-spring-framework.html

Comment: thanks, smuco. I've already found that this property can be written in hst-config.properties file which overrides SpringComponentManager.properties